# Triage audit failure message says that spam or nonsense should be 'flagged for closure'

Tags: bug, status-review, review-audits, user-interface, triage

I 'failed' a Triage audit and saw this message: [(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vub17.png) (Emphasis mine)

> #### STOP! Look and listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This question is spam or nonsense; no reasonable amount of improvement would make it appropriate. It should be **flagged for closure.**

However, as the Meta and Stack Overflow moderators alike would be happy to tell you, you should not vote/flag spam for **closure,** you should **flag it as spam.** Closing as spam has been [removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15634/1377755) for a long time.

Should we be telling users who fail Triage audits to close spam? I think not. I suggest to have this text updated to say:

> It should be flagged as spam or rude or abusive.

<sup>Side note: I did not actually fail that audit. If I duplicate the audit tab before passing it, and then do so, I can go to the other tab and 'fail' it, to see the failure message without it actually counting as a failed audit. Why did you do that, you ask? Because I was curious what would happen.</sup>

<sub>Also since the [Triage queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) is [almost](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/triage) exclusive to Stack Overflow I thought this would be more appropriate here rather than on [the Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).</sub>

Comment: Was it actually spam? You didn’t link to the audit

Comment: @SecurityHound [Yes it was.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/35290839)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/35290839

Comment: This is an edge-case that should be addressed. Smoke Detector is effective enough that in 9.9 out of 10 cases, if it's spam and in the review queue, it's an audit, so I know to verify that by navigating to the question, then skip (or flag to close). But this should not occur.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't be prompting folks to flag for closure like that. Please don't vote to close spam. We can and do warn folks about that